# I have already installed composer but while running command in command prompt It's showing an error.?

Tags: laravel

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqNY5.png)
This was error which i got while installing laravel.. I have reinstalled xampp then also there is a same error..!

Comment: can anyone help me ..

Comment: What version is PHP? Also, if your computer date correct?

Comment: @nbrogi I am using current php version5.6.20 and my computer date is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related to this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/442793/why-cant-curl-properly-verify-a-certificate-on-windows

Try running this in the command line:

```
cd <SOME_DIRECTORY>

wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem --no-check-certificate

set COMPOSER_CAFILE=<SOME_DIRECTORY>/cacert.pem
```

Then, try installing again.

Comment: It's saying wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem --no-check-certificate
'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: where to save cacert.pem

Comment: <SOME_DIRECTORY>

Comment: Put this command: set COMPOSER_CAFILE=<SOME_DIRECTORY>/cacert.pem. 
Then, try installing again (obviously, replace <SOME_DIRECTORY> with your directory)

Comment: can i connect with u via team viewer

Comment: You might have some other issue. Sorry I couldn't help.